# How does Assert.AreEqual determine equality between two generic IEnumerables?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, ienumerable, mstest, assert

I have a unit test to check whether a method returns the correct `IEnumerable`.  The method builds the enumerable using `yield return`.  The class that it is an enumerable of is below:

```
enum TokenType
{
    NUMBER,
    COMMAND,
    ARITHMETIC,
}

internal class Token
{
    public TokenType type { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public static bool operator == (Token lh, Token rh) { return (lh.type == rh.type) && (lh.text == rh.text); }
    public static bool operator != (Token lh, Token rh) { return !(lh == rh); }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return text.GetHashCode() % type.GetHashCode();
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this == (Token)obj;
    }
}
```

This is the relevant part of the method:

```
 foreach (var lookup in REGEX_MAPPING)
 {
     if (lookup.re.IsMatch(s))
     {
         yield return new Token { type = lookup.type, text = s };
         break;
     }
 }
```

If I store the result of this method in `actual`, make another enumerable `expected`, and compare them like this...

```
  Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

..., the assertion fails.

I wrote an extension method for `IEnumerable` that is similar to [Python's `zip` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) (it combines two IEnumerables into a set of pairs) and tried this:

```
foreach(Token[] t in expected.zip(actual))
{
    Assert.AreEqual(t[0], t[1]);
}
```

It worked!  So what is the difference between these two `Assert.AreEqual`s?

Comment: @Jason Baker: please don't take this the wrong way, have you considered that the fact you have to ask a question like this, might mean you are making things too complicated?

Comment: Erm... no, not really.  :-)  Could you point me towards where I'm making things complicated?

Comment: Also, I'm not convinced that using "text.GetHashCode() % type.GetHashCode();" as a return value for GetHashCode() is a good idea...

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - I'm not sure either... but that's the subject of a different question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Assert.AreEqual` is going to compare the two objects at hand. `IEnumerable`s are types in and of themselves, and provide a mechanism to iterate over some collection...but they are not actually that collection. Your original comparison compared two `IEnumerable`s, which is a valid comparison...but not what you needed. You needed to compare *what the two `IEnumerable`s were intended to enumerate*.

Here is how I compare two enumerables:

```
Assert.AreEqual(t1.Count(), t2.Count());

IEnumerator<Token> e1 = t1.GetEnumerator();
IEnumerator<Token> e2 = t2.GetEnumerator();

while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext())
{
    Assert.AreEqual(e1.Current, e2.Current);
}
```

I am not sure whether the above is less code than your `.Zip` method, but it is about as simple as it gets.

Comment: This makes sense.  Is there not any way to compare the two IEnumerables object by object without having to write as much code as it took?

Comment: I would just use a while loop. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: I found another way that works and is simpler.  I'll accept this since you showed why my code wasn't working though.  :-)

Comment: Some pointers: that approach involves checking both sequences twice (once for count, once per item) - not very efficient. Plus, IEnumerator<T> is IDisposable, so should involve "using". Finally, you can use EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(e1.Current,e2.Current) to avoid boxing etc.

Comment: Yes, it does iterate twice...but it is a simple implementation. ;) There is a more complex version that gets the job done more efficiently, but with less clarity. If your comparing two very large enumerations, a more efficient method would be required, but I like the clarity of mine. (However, using statements should indeed be used...left out for brevity.)

Answer (score 90):

Found it:

```
Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEqual(actual));
```

Comment: Nice find! I didn't even know there was a SequenceEqual() extension. Ty!

Comment: This won't tell you any information about which element was unequal when the test fails; it will just tell you that it failed. The CollectionAssert mechanism suggested by jerryjvl gives much richer failure information.

Comment: Be sure to include System.Linq in your using directives.

Answer (score 49):

Have you considered using the `CollectionAssert` class instead...considering that it is intended to perform equality checks on collections?

**Addendum:**
If the 'collections' being compared are enumerations, then simply wrapping them with '`new List<T>(enumeration)`' is the easiest way to perform the comparison. Constructing a new list causes some overhead of course, but in the context of a unit test this should not matter too much I hope?

Comment: All the methods in CollectionAssert are set to compare against ICollections though. I have IEnumerables. Is there any easy way to change them to ICollections?

Comment: In cases like that I normally just do a quick wrap-up in a `new List<T>(enumeration)` so that I can perform the comparison. It's not like the overhead is likely to be a problem in the context of a unit test.

Comment: Just do .ToArray() on both arguments when using CollectionAssert.

Answer (score 21):

I think the simplest and clearest way to assert the equality you want is a combination of the answer by jerryjvl and comment on his post by MEMark - combine `CollectionAssert.AreEqual` with extension methods:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected.ToArray(), actual.ToArray());
```

This gives richer error information than the SequenceEqual answer suggested by the OP (it will tell you which element was found that was unexpected). For example:

```
IEnumerable<string> expected = new List<string> { "a", "b" };
IEnumerable<string> actual   = new List<string> { "a", "c" }; // mismatching second element

CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected.ToArray(), actual.ToArray());
// Helpful failure message!
//  CollectionAssert.AreEqual failed. (Element at index 1 do not match.)    

Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEqual(actual));
// Mediocre failure message:
//  Assert.IsTrue failed.
```

You'll be *really* pleased you did it this way if/when your test fails - sometimes you can even know what's wrong without having to break out the debugger - and hey you're doing TDD right, so you write a failing test first, right? ;-)

The error messages get even more helpful if you're using `AreEquivalent` to test for equivalence (order doesn't matter):

```
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expected.ToList(), actual.ToList());
// really helpful error message!
//  CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent failed. The expected collection contains 1
//  occurrence(s) of <b>. The actual collection contains 0 occurrence(s).
```