# Union-ing two custom classes returns duplicates

Tags: c#, linq, set, union, equals

I have two custom classes, `ChangeRequest` and `ChangeRequests`, where a `ChangeRequests` can contain many `ChangeRequest` instances.

```
public class ChangeRequests : IXmlSerializable, ICloneable, IEnumerable<ChangeRequest>,
    IEquatable<ChangeRequests> { ... }

public class ChangeRequest : ICloneable, IXmlSerializable, IEquatable<ChangeRequest>
    { ... }
```

I am trying to do a union of two `ChangeRequests` instances.  However, duplicates do not seem to be removed.  My MSTest unit test is as follows:

```
var cr1 = new ChangeRequest { CRID = "12" };
var crs1 = new ChangeRequests { cr1 };
var crs2 = new ChangeRequests
               {
                   cr1.Clone(),
                   new ChangeRequest { CRID = "34" }
               };
Assert.AreEqual(crs1[0], crs2[0], "First CR in both ChangeRequests should be equal");
var unionedCRs = new ChangeRequests(crs1.Union<ChangeRequest>(crs2));
ChangeRequests expected = crs2.Clone();
Assert.AreEqual(expected, unionedCRs, "Duplicates should be removed from a Union");
```

The test fails in the last line, and `unionedCRs` contains two copies of `cr1`.  When I tried to debug and step through each line, I had a breakpoint in `ChangeRequest.Equals(object)` on the first line, as well as in the first line of `ChangeRequest.Equals(ChangeRequest)`, but neither were hit.  Why does the union contain duplicate `ChangeRequest` instances?

**Edit:** as requested, here is `ChangeRequests.Equals(ChangeRequests)`:

```
public bool Equals(ChangeRequests other)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return null != other && this.SequenceEqual<ChangeRequest>(other);
}
```

And here's `ChangeRequests.Equals(object)`:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return Equals(obj as ChangeRequests);
}
```

**Edit:** I overrode `GetHashCode` on both `ChangeRequest` and `ChangeRequests` but still in my test, if I do `IEnumerable<ChangeRequest> unionedCRsIEnum = crs1.Union<ChangeRequest>(crs2);`, `unionedCRsIEnum` ends up with two copies of the `ChangeRequest` with `CRID` 12.

**Edit:**  something has to be up with my `Equals` or `GetHashCode` implementations somewhere, since `Assert.AreEqual(expected, unionedCRs.Distinct(), "Distinct should remove duplicates");` fails, and the string representations of `expected` and `unionedCRs.Distinct()` show that `unionedCRs.Distinct()` definitely has two copies of CR 12.

Comment: Can you post your implementation of `ChangeRequests.Equals` and `ChangeRequests.GetHashCode`? It's easy to make a typo in one of these and break object identity.

Comment: @Tim:  I added to my question both implementations of `ChangeRequests.Equals`, but I haven't overridden `GetHashCode`...  Maybe I should do that!

Comment: Right, your `GetHashCode` needs to be consistent with your `Equals` - the `Union` method does appear to use both.

Comment: You should absolutely override GetHashCode. I'm surprised the compiler hasn't already warned you about that.

Comment: @Tim:  you should post your "fix `GetHashCode`" suggestion as an answer--I would select it as the chosen one!  Turns out it was a `GetHashCode` problem.  `Union` works as expected now.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your `GetHashCode` implementation is consistent with your `Equals` - the `Enumerable.Union` method does appear to use both.

You should get a warning from the compiler if you've implemented one but not the other; it's still up to you to make sure that both methods agree with each other. Here's a convenient summary of the rules: [Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overriden-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that `Assert.AreEqual()` examines *the contents* of the sequence - it compares the sequence objects themselves, which are clearly not equal.

What you want is a `SequenceEqual()` method, that will actually examine the contents of two sequences. [This answer may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933285/how-does-assert-areequal-determine-equality-between-two-generic-ienumerables/933294#933294). It's a response to a similar question, that describes how to compare to `IEnumerable<>` sequences.

You could easily take the responder's answer, and create an extension method to make the calls look more like assertions:

```
public static class AssertionExt
{
  public static bool AreSequencesEqual<T>( IEnumerable<T> expected, 
                                           IEnumerable<T> sequence )
  {
    Assert.AreEqual(expected.Count(), sequence .Count()); 

    IEnumerator<Token> e1 = expected.GetEnumerator(); 
    IEnumerator<Token> e2 = sequence .GetEnumerator(); 

    while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext()) 
    { 
        Assert.AreEqual(e1.Current, e2.Current); 
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could use [`SequenceEqual()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx), to compare the sequences, realizing that it won't provide any information about *which* elements are not equal.

Comment: Trying `SequenceEqual` still failed.  I have overridden `Equals` on `ChangeRequests`, so calling `AreEqual` on two `ChangeRequests` should work.  My `ChangeRequests.Equals` override compares the sequences.

Comment: @Sarah - it's odd that `SequenceEqual` wouldn't work - it should use the default equality comparer, which in turn, should test T for being `IEquatable<T>`, and use the equality comparer appropriate to that implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As LBushkin says, `Assert.AreEqual` will just call `Equals` on the sequences.

You can use the [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) extension method though:

```
Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEqual(unionedCRs));
```

That won't give much information if it fails, however.

You may want to use the [test code we wrote for MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/) which was sequence-focused - if the sequences aren't equal, it will specify in what way they differ. (I'm trying to get a link to the source file in question, but my network connection is rubbish.)

Comment: I have overridden `Equals` on `ChangeRequests`, so using `AreEqual` should work, I think.  Replacing the last line of my test with `Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEqual<ChangeRequest>(unionedCRs), "Duplicates should be removed from a Union");` still failed.

Comment: @Sarah: With Assert.Equal, it's not calling Equals on your ChangeRequests type - it's calling Equals on the *sequence*, which won't override Equals. It should work with SequenceEqual though.