# Why does this test method fail?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

Here's my test function (c#, visual studio 2010):

```
[TestMethod()]
public void TestGetRelevantWeeks()
{
List<sbyte> expected = new List<sbyte>() { 2, 1, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45 };
List<sbyte> actual = new List<sbyte>() { 2, 1, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45 };
Assert.AreEqual<List<sbyte>>(expected, actual);
}
```

**Exception:**
Failed  TestGetRelevantWeek   Assert.AreEqual failed.
Expected:System.Collections.Generic.List 1[System.SByte].
Actual:System.Collections.Generic.List 1[System.SByte].

---

Does AreEqual only check equality of the reference, not the contents?

But then, the exception message would be confusing. I also couldn't find a documentation of the default equality comparer for a generic list.

Could you help to clarify why the test fails and what would be solutions for testing the equality of the contents of both lists?

Kind regards

Comment: The *default* on classes is always reference equality. The lack of any documentation to the contrary usually means the default still applies.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `Assert.AreEqual()` method does a reference equality test as you expected.

Assuming you're using .Net 3.5 or above, you can do this:

```
using System.Linq;

Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEqual(actual));
```

Edit: Clarified when this option is available.

Answer (score 13):

> Does AreEqual only check equality of the reference, not the contents?

Yeap.

To test the contents you could:

```
Assert.AreEqual(expected.Count, actual.Count);
for (var i = 0; i < expected.Count; i++)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(expected[i], actual[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I accepted you answer because SequenceEqual(...) in the other answers is not supported by List<> generic collections. Your solutions works :-)

Comment: @nabulke: It is if you're targetting the .Net 3.5 framework or above and you have `using System.Linq;` in your file. But you're right, Darin's answer will always work.

Answer (score 5):

I think that this is what your are looking for:

```
Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEqual(actual));
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933285/how-does-assert-areequal-determine-equality-between-two-generic-ienumerables) question

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `CollectionAssert` instead of `Assert`:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

I think it is much more simple and fancier than a loop over the collection of your test cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEqual(actual));
Assert.IsTrue(expected.SequenceEqual(actual));
```

These options don't work for me.

Probably the only viable option.
Had to use this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < expected.Count; i++)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(expected[i], actual[i]);
        }
```