# Unit Test failing when comparing two ILists

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, ilist

I am running some [TestMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182517%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) thats tests the implementation of a JSON serialiser and when comparing two IList objects before and after the serialisation \ de-serialisation but the comparison is failing.

**Model**

```
public class BusinessModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Test**

```
IList<BusinessModel> model = new List<BusinessModel>
{
    new BusinessModel { ID = 1, Name = "Test1" },
    new BusinessModel { ID = 2, Name = "Test2" },
    new BusinessModel { ID = 3, Name = "Test3" },
    new BusinessModel { ID = 4, Name = "Test4" }
};

[TestMethod]
public async Task TestSerialiseDeserialiseIsEqual()
{
    ISerialiser serialiser = new Serialiser();

    IList<BusinessModel> deserialisedModel;
    string serialised = string.Empty;

    serialised = await serialiser.SerialiseAsync<IList<BusinessModel>>(model);
    deserialisedModel = await serialiser.DeserialiseAsync<IList<BusinessModel>>(serialised);

    Assert.IsTrue(model.SequenceEqual(deserialisedModel));
}
```

**Results**

I have tried a number of test methods detail in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933285/how-does-assert-areequal-determine-equality-between-two-generic-ienumerables) post but all are failing.

```
Assert.AreEqual(t1.Count(), t2.Count());

IEnumerator<Token> e1 = t1.GetEnumerator();
IEnumerator<Token> e2 = t2.GetEnumerator();

while (e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext())
{
    Assert.AreEqual(e1.Current, e2.Current);
}
```

passes the collection count items but fails on the first object comparison.

```
Assert.IsTrue(model.SequenceEqual(deserialisedModel));
```

fails with `Assert.IsTrue failed`

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(model.ToArray(),deserialisedModel.ToArray())
```

fails with `Collection.AreEqual failed (Element at index 0 do not match)`

```
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(model.ToArray(),deserialisedModel.ToArray())
```

fails with `{"CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent failed. The expected collection contains 1 occurrence(s) of <Helper.Tests.Serialisation.BusinessModel>. The actual collection contains 0 occurrence(s). "}`

From checking the objects they look the same

**Original**

[image]

**Deserialised Object**

[image]

**Question**

What is the best method in comparing IList objects for Unit Testing? Why are my tests failing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for your `BusinessModel` class. The default `Equals` implementation is reference equality, and your object references will be different for the items in the two lists.

Alternatively you can create an `IEqualityComparer<BusinessModel>` which defines equality/hash code and pass that to `SequenceEquals`.

Comment: Thanks Lee. Overriding the Equals and GetHashCode methods sorted the problem