# Get webpage text in List<string> and compare it with other hard codded List<string>

Tags: c#

I have 3 classes , First class in which we write methods, second we call the methods, third in which we use it for our execution.

In the First Class i have written below c# code to retrieve all the row text in webpage through selenium.

```
public void GetUsedChecklistRecords()
{
    SelectElement records  = new SelectElement(reportsDr.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(text(),'Benefit Checklist')]")));
    IList<IWebElement> options = records.Options;
    foreach(IWebElement option in options)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(option.Text);
    }
}
```

I am confused how to call it in second class and then use it in third class which looks as below

```
public void ChecklistUsedReportsTest()
{
    reportsPage.SelectRE("Reporting Entity 02");
    List<String> WorkPaperName = new List<String>(new String[] {"Entertainment","Loan" });
    List<String> reportName = new List<string>(new String[] {"Entertainment Benefit Checklist","Loan Benefit Checklist"});
    for (int a = 0; a < WorkPaperName.Count; a++)
    {
        reportsPage.NavigateToChecklist(WorkPaperName[a]);
        var ActualRecords= reportsPage.GetUsedChecklistRecords();
        List<string> difference = ActualRecords.Except(reportName).ToList();
        foreach (var value in difference)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
        Assert.AreEqual(reportName,ActualRecords);
}}
```

It's not working, please help how to proceed. because the method in the first class is void then it should be called as void only in second class, but then how should i use it to compare in third class

Comment: You will need to change the method in the first class. Right now it does not return anything, it looks like it just prints the text to the console.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to return `IEnumerable<string>` from `GetUsedChecklistRecords`

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetUsedChecklistRecords()
{
    SelectElement records  = new SelectElement(reportsDr.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(text(),'Benefit Checklist')]")));
    IList<IWebElement> options = records.Options;
    return options.Select(it => it.Text);
 }

  public void ChecklistUsedReportsTest()
  {
     reportsPage.SelectRE("Reporting Entity 02");
     List<String> WorkPaperNames = new List<String>(new String[] {"Entertainment","Loan" });
     List<String> reportNames = new List<string>(new String[] {"Entertainment Benefit Checklist","Loan Benefit Checklist"});
     var actualRecords= reportsPage.GetUsedChecklistRecords();  
     // assume reportNames and actualRecords has no duplicate elements
     var areEqual = reportNames.All(it => actualRecords.Any(ti => it == ti));   
     List<string> difference = actualRecords.Except(reportNames).ToList();

     foreach(var workPaperName in WorkPaperNames)
     {
         reportsPage.NavigateToChecklist(workPaperName);
         foreach (var value in difference)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(value);
         }

         Console.ReadLine();  

     }}
```

Notes

- `Assert.AreEqual` won't check if two ienumerable has [the same elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933285/how-does-assert-areequal-determine-equality-between-two-generic-ienumerables)
- It's good practice to name collections name in plural (`WorkPapers` instead of `WorkPaper`
- `reportNames` and `actualRecords` aren't modified inside `foreach` loop, so you can calculate `difference` and equality once, instead of on each iteration
- Use `foreach` instead of `for` whenever possible

Comment: its giving me error for GetUsedChecklistRecords() as "Element should have been “select” but was “div”"....... Does it means my path is incorrect?

Comment: In fact you get error on `SelectElement records  = new Sel...` line, yes, that means that `//div[contains(text(),'Benefit Checklist')]` is invalid

Comment: i modified my code as below for all the three classes 
        public IEnumerable<string> GetUsedChecklistRecords()
        {
            IList<IWebElement> options = reportsDr.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(text(),'Benefit Checklist')]"));
            List<string> records = new List<string>();
            foreach (IWebElement element in options)
            {
                records.Add(element.ToString());
            }
            return options.Select(it => it.Text);
        }

Comment: class reportpage.cs as below                                                                                        
        public IEnumerable<string> GetUsedChecklistRecords()
        {
            return reportsHelper.GetUsedChecklistRecords();
        }